# How is the speed of light calculated in Hartree units?

Tags: speed-of-light, units

I understand that the speed of light in [Hartree units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units) in the inverse of the fine structure constant but I am most unclear as to how this is derived.  Can someone walk me through the math and logic?

Answer (score 3):

The fine structure conatant in mksi units is $$\alpha = \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \hbar c }\,.$$ In Hartree units $e=\hbar=4\pi\epsilon_0=1$ hence the result.